# Element pr not allowed as child of element body in this context

Tags: html

I can't get one of my paragraphs to seperate, it's stuck to the end of the previous one and I can't figure out where I went wrong

```
<p><strong>Weekly quizzes:</strong>are short online quizzes completed at the beginning of your tutorial. See the Scghedule above for the topics and 
            dates of these quizzes. In general they cover the material from the previous lectures and are closed book. </p>
<pr><strong>Lab Excercises:</strong>in the tutorial your tutor will review the completion of your completed lab excercises. You are encouraged to attempt 
            to complete the set excercises before your tutorial so you have time to discuss any issues that arise with your tutor and have time to get them 
            marked off.</pr>
<pr><strong>Assignments: Parts 1, 2 and 3:</strong> are incremental instalments of a web site development task. In Part 1 you will demonstrate your ability 
            to develop and deploy on a server well-structured, linked Web pages with text, graphics, tables and forms, styled with CSS. Part 2 further extends the 
            use of HTML elements and makes use of JavaScript to validate forms and add dynamic behaviour to the Web page. In Part 3 you will use forms to submit 
            and retrieve data from a server using PHP and MySQL. </pr>
```

I've tried shifting around the format and rewriting that segment but it hasn't separated the paragraphs

Comment: I've edited your question so that it restored the actual text of the code you posted originally instead of a picture of text you added later. Please do not post images of your code. This makes it easier for people to help you and for others to find this question in a search if they have similar issues in the future. Please read over the answers to this question to understand a bit more about this: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<pr>` is not an HTML element.  Perhaps you are thinking of `<br>` instead to add a line break?

However I see you are trying to wrap text in `<pr>text</pr>` so I'm not entirely clear on what it is you are trying to accomplish here.  Perhaps you mean `<pre>` ?

Here's your code with `<br>` tags added

```html
<p>
  <strong>Weekly quizzes:</strong>are short online quizzes completed at the beginning of your tutorial. See the Scghedule above for the topics and dates of these quizzes. In general they cover the material from the previous lectures and are closed book.
</p>

<br/>
<p>
  <strong>Lab Excercises:</strong>in the tutorial your tutor will review the completion of your completed lab excercises. You are encouraged to attempt to complete the set excercises before your tutorial so you have time to discuss any issues that arise with your tutor and have time to get them marked off.
</p>
            
<br/>
<p>
  <strong>Assignments: Parts 1, 2 and 3:</strong> are incremental instalments of a web site development task. In Part 1 you will demonstrate your ability to develop and deploy on a server well-structured, linked Web pages with text, graphics, tables and forms, styled with CSS. Part 2 further extends the use of HTML elements and makes use of JavaScript to validate forms and add dynamic behaviour to the Web page. In Part 3 you will use forms to submit and retrieve data from a server using PHP and MySQL.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no HTML tag called `<pr>` defined in the official HTML specifications.

The code in below should solve your problem:

```
<p>
    <strong>Weekly quizzes:</strong>
    are short online quizzes completed at the beginning of your tutorial. See the Scghedule above for the topics and 
    dates of these quizzes. In general they cover the material from the previous lectures and are closed book. 
</p>
<p>
    <strong>Lab Excercises:</strong>
    in the tutorial your tutor will review the completion of your completed lab excercises. You are encouraged to attempt 
    to complete the set excercises before your tutorial so you have time to discuss any issues that arise with your tutor and have time to get them 
    marked off.
</p>
<p>
    <strong>Assignments: Parts 1, 2 and 3:</strong>
    are incremental instalments of a web site development task. In Part 1 you will demonstrate your ability 
    to develop and deploy on a server well-structured, linked Web pages with text, graphics, tables and forms, styled with CSS. Part 2 further extends the 
    use of HTML elements and makes use of JavaScript to validate forms and add dynamic behaviour to the Web page. In Part 3 you will use forms to submit 
    and retrieve data from a server using PHP and MySQL.
</p>
```

Looks like this:

**Weekly quizzes:**
    are short online quizzes completed at the beginning of your tutorial. See the Scghedule above for the topics and 
    dates of these quizzes. In general they cover the material from the previous lectures and are closed book.

**Lab Excercises:**
    in the tutorial your tutor will review the completion of your completed lab excercises. You are encouraged to attempt 
    to complete the set excercises before your tutorial so you have time to discuss any issues that arise with your tutor and have time to get them 
    marked off.

**Assignments: Parts 1, 2 and 3:**
    are incremental instalments of a web site development task. In Part 1 you will demonstrate your ability 
    to develop and deploy on a server well-structured, linked Web pages with text, graphics, tables and forms, styled with CSS. Part 2 further extends the 
    use of HTML elements and makes use of JavaScript to validate forms and add dynamic behaviour to the Web page. In Part 3 you will use forms to submit 
    and retrieve data from a server using PHP and MySQL.